# Synonym [astronauts] and [astronaut]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[astronauts](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronauts) is the more used of the two. [astronaut](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronaut) has only 5 questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merged [astronaut](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronaut) to [astronauts](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronauts). All questions have automatically been retagged.